# Why is python showing less memory than it use and how to manage memory properly?

Tags: python

I am working in Jupyter Notebook.

My main task in simple words is adding a big amount of numbers to list:

```
preds = []
for i in range(0,100000000):
    preds.append(np.int8(0))
```

After execution of code above I call `sys.getsizeof` to see how many memory array `preds` holds and it shows `835128600 bytes`, as expected, but if I open task manager I will see that process `python3` holds 4.3 gigabytes of memory.

After execution of  `preds = []` process `python3` loses all that 4.3 gigabytes. I considered it as a hint that actually allocated memory for array `preds` is bigger than it showed by `sys.getsizeof`.

So my question is how to prevent Python from using such big amount of memory?

Comment: `preds` is a list with 1e8 elements, and therefore the *list itself* occupies 8e8 bytes of memory - that's all that `sys.getsizeof()` tells you.  The elements of that list occupy about 32 bytes each, far more in total than the list itself.  Basically, storing individual numpy scalar values in a Python list is the worst thing you could possibly do.  If they were all in a single numpy array, the memory usage would only be a bit more than 1e8 bytes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you advice me some method to solve my problem? I mean i can't use native python int numbers because every number occupy a lot of memory. In the same time i can't use numpy array because i need adding to back of array and numpy appending is even slower than python's implementation

Comment: Every `np.int8` value (as a Python object) takes up just as much memory as an `int`. It's a Numpy array that uses memory more efficiently when it knows that its elements will be limited to 8 bits each.

Comment: Do you not have any idea ahead of time how big the array will be?  You could pre-allocate it with the final size, and just fill it in as you go, rather than appending.

Comment: slow append method, i don't know size of elements so i can't create numpy array with determined size
one of possible variants to use very large numpy array and crop it with actual size of elements

Comment: Somewhat less trivial, you can define your own class that stores a list of Numpy arrays. You can add new arrays as necessary to that list, and fill in the last array with values as necessary, as recommended by jasonharper. (This is similar to how `int` itself is defined; it's a linked list of 32-bit values, each of which represents a single digit (in a huge base) of the number.)